# Error with Wagtail URLs for media files: subclasses of Storage must provide a url() method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, wagtail

I am using Wagtail in a project and have a problem with both wagtailimages.Image and wagtaildocs.Document fields. When using DRF to access the URL data I get a "subclasses of Storage must provide a url() method" error. My configuration is that I have to use Bunny.net for storing media files. In order to do that, I use a library called django-bunny-storage (https://pypi.org/project/django-bunny-storage/) that works well with non Wagtail projects.
This is my simplified model in which I removed all other fields:

```
class Content(models.Model):
    illustration = models.ForeignKey(
    'wagtailimages.Image',
    null=True,
    blank=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    related_name="+",
    )
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtaildocs.Document',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="+",
    )
    panels = [
        ImageChooserPanel('illustration'),
        DocumentChooserPanel('document'),
    ]
```

As per django-bunny-storage I also had to modify the template context_processors array

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media'

            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I created a small modelserializer for Content that always returns this same error when I try to access the url of the Document or the Image field.

```
from wagtail.images.models import Image, AbstractImage, AbstractRendition
from wagtail.documents.models import Document


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = (('file'),)
        


class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = (('file'),)


class ContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    illustration = ImageSerializer(read_only=True)
    document = DocumentSerializer(read_only=True) 
    pk=serializers.UUIDField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = Content
        fields = '_all_'
```

Any idea what it might be?
Many thanks

Comment: What version of django-bunny-storage are you using? It looks like a `url()` method was added in version 0.1.1: https://github.com/willmeyers/django-bunny-storage/releases

Comment: @gasman using this version 0.1.1